# High TLB Shootdown Counts are Affecting Performance

Tags: redhat, interrupts

We are running an app in JBoss EAP on RHEL 6.7 and are experiencing significantly different performance across the cluster. Of the 8 VMs, most will respond to requests in ~200ms but one or two will have response times of 2 or 4 seconds.

Investigating the issue, we observed from vmstat that the slower servers report hundreds of thousands of system interrupts every 5 seconds compared to a few thousand on the fast servers. Moving to /proc/interrupts we saw that the interrupts were TLB Shootdowns. 100k to 200k of them every few seconds.

I've done some reading to understand what these are ([I like this description best).](http://zinascii.com/2015/illumos-5498.html) But I don't know where to look next. Why are the TLB interrupts being issued?

Comment: Did some reading on ksmd. Is this a process that should run on a VM or on a hypervisor? [Kernel.og KSM Paper](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/ksm.txt)

Comment: Are you swapping heavily? (i.e. insufficient menory)?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2271